# Do comet tails increase as comets move away from the Sun?

Tags: comets

Do the tails of comets increase on their return trip from the Sun?

Comment: What do you mean with *increase*? Why do you think so?

Comment: I think increase is self-evident in the context, as in, a longer tail during recession.

Comment: Comet tails as seen from Earth can grow, shrink, or vanish entirely during the course of the comets journey through the inner solar system, depending both on what happens to the comets' supply of dust and volatiles and the relative geometry of the comets' orbits to that of the earth.

Comment: @antlersoft I think you should expand this into an answer

Comment: It seems likely that both the decreased cometary activity from lower solar heating, and the comet itself catching up to already-emitted dust and gas would result in a shorter tail as it recedes from the sun.

Answer (score 1):

The only data I could find indicates that the brightness is similar approaching and receding:
[image]
[Source](https://openspacescience.blog/2018/11/06/stand-by-for-comet-wirtanen-but-dont-get-too-excited/)
This is for the unusual almost "tailless" [Comet Wirtanen](https://openspacescience.blog/2018/11/06/stand-by-for-comet-wirtanen-but-dont-get-too-excited/) .